# Variable 'message' might not have been initialized

Tags: java

Добрый день. Есть у меня функция, которая определяет, какой элемент из меню был нажат. Правда столкнулся с непонятной ошибкой. Объявляю в начале ф-и строку `message`, а потом изменяю её (в соответствии с элементом, на который пришёлся клик). Но в конце функции, где я хочу вывести тост, который покажет, на какой именно элемент нажал пользователь, я получаю ошибку, мол я переменную не инициализировал. Но как я её не инициализировал, если я менял её значение в процессе функции?

P.S. Всё работает, если декларировать и инициализировать переменную сразу, т.е.

`String.message = "";`

Привожу код:

```
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    String message;

    int id = item.getItemId();

    switch(id) {
        case R.id.menu_item1:
            message = "menu item 1";

            break;

        case R.id.menu_item2:
            message = "menu item 2";

            break;

        case R.id.menu_item3:
            message = "menu item 3";

            break;
    }

    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    return true;
}
```

Comment: Видимо либо стоит сразу инициализировать переменную `message` , либо добавить в оператор выбора условие `default`, но лучше наверно просто пустой строкой инициализировать.

Comment: переменная назначается, я проверял

Comment: В Java не существует для локальных переменных значения по умолчанию, так что они должны быть объявлены и начальное значение должны быть присвоено перед первым использованием.

Comment: @ikerya, так у вас при вызове метода `onOptionsItemSelected` переменная `message` каждый раз заново инициализируется, точнее не инициализируется, поэтому стоит предусмотреть варианты, упомянутые выше

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ошибка говорит, что переменная **могла** быть не инициализирована. Представьте, что по какой-то причине `id` не равен ни одному из 3х вариантов внутри `switch`. Тогда присвоения переменной `message` не произойдет нигде.

Ваши варианты:

- инициализировать переменную значением или `null`-ом перед switch;
- инициализировать переменную значением или `null`-ом, добавив внутрь `switch` секцию `default`:

  ```
  switch(id) {
     case ....
     case ....
     default: message = "";
  }
  ```
- бросать `new IllegalArgumentException()` или `new IllegalStateException()` из секции `default`, если неожиданный `id` потенциально деструктивен.